# Failing HTTP request for localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost

I am using RestClient to get a URL in a Rake task.

I'm getting this error:

```
the scheme http does not accept registry part: :80 (or bad hostname?)
```

on the second line here:

```
def check_url url
  RestClient.get('http://localhost:2828'){ |response, request, result, &block|
     case response.code
     when 200
      return true
     else
      # response.return!(request, result, &block)
       return false
      end
    }
 end
```

What am I missing? `RestClient.get` with localhost works fine for me in the console.

Any help would be great.

Comment: When doing it from the console, are you also using port `2828` there? Is your local host configured to accept requests on that port? Perhaps when running the Rails console, it opens that port for service? What command line do you use to open the console?

Comment: @mbratch I'm using Rails console. And the host is running using Rails server. I tried using ngrok and trying that domain but surprisingly I get the same error.

Comment: OK so you aren't specifying a custom port. I was just wondering about the `2828`. I assume you have your local host configured to accept requests on that port (it wouldn't be so by default).

Comment: @mbratch ah sorry, you reminded me, I'm using foreman and specifying 2828 for development in the procfile. I get the same results if I using the default :3000 with Rails server